# Bash sed match a string with newlines above and below

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Here's an excerpt of a text file.

```
http_server = Server(
    uuid = "9a44b850-c54f-11e3-9c1a-0800200c9a66",
)

# https_server = Server(
#     uuid = "0c9cb0c0-c55e-11e3-9c1a-0800200c9a66",
# )
```

I want to use sed (or something similar) to extract the: "0c9cb0c0-c55e-11e3-9c1a-0800200c9a66" out of the file.

I've tried `cat server.conf | sed -n 's/.*uuid = "\(.*\)",/\1/p'` but it gives me both uuids. When I put in newlines like `\n` the sed doesn't work at all.

The unique marker for the uuid is `https_server`, the regex must make sure the uuid was inside the `https_server`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
cat server.conf | sed -n -e '/https_server/{N;p}' | sed -n -e 's/.*uuid = "\([^ ]*\)",/\1/p'
```

Or this invoking sed once only:

```
cat server.conf | sed -n -e '/https_server/{N;s/.*uuid = "\([^ ]*\)",/\1/p}'
```

Or if there is chance of multiple empty lines between the https_server and uuid line inside the block:

```
cat server.conf | sed -n -e '/https_server/,/uuid/p' | sed -n -e 's/.*uuid = "\([^ ]*\)",/\1/p'
```

Comment: One problem is that the file may or may not have a `#`. However I want it to differentiate it by the `https_server`.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify that `https_server` boundary is important.

Comment: So if it happens to not have # in front of the second https_server and uuid as per your example how do you differentiate the two? I take, in that case you would still only want to find the first uuid, right?

Comment: No I want to find the uuid that is inside https_server block.

Answer (score 0):

For making sure the `uuid` is inside the `https_server`, you can skip all lines until you reach that string:

```
cat server.conf | sed -n '/https_server/,//{//!p}' | sed -n 's/.*uuid = "\(.*\)",/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

This one looks for a `https_server` line which is possibly commented out, then extracts any `uuid` in the block which follows before the next closing parenthesis.

```
sed -n '/^#* *https_server *=.*(/,/)/!d;/^#* *uuid *= *"/!d;s///;s/",//p' searver.conf
```

This avoids the [useless use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) and the silly multiple `sed` invocations.

```
/regex/,/regex/
```

selects a region.  The action `!d` simply discards any lines outside of this region.

```
/^ *uuid *= *"/
```

selects any line in the region matching this pattern.  Again, `!d` discards any line which is not selected.

```
s///
```

deletes the previously matched pattern.

Finally,

```
s/",//
```

removes the quote and the comma at the end of the string.

Some `sed` dialects might want you to backslash the literal parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/https_server/{n;s/.*uuid = "([^"]*)".*/\1/p;q}' server.conf
```

If the `uuid` is not on the next line but some other following line, use:

```
sed -rn '/https_server/{:a;n;/\)\s*$/b;s/.*uuid = "([^"]*)".*/\1/p;Ta;q}' server.conf
```